# Best practice for setting the holes required for attaching an external module

Tags: openscad

I'm new in OpenSCAD.

I have a board on which I want to attach a stepper. For this I need 5 holes in the board - one for the shaft and 4 for the screws.
I draw the board and the holes in the main scad-file and use the stepper as a module.
My problem is, whenever I want to replace the stepper, I have to replace the holes.
Is there a good practice for this? Currently I've defined the holes in the stepper-module file as an independent module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define holes inside of your stepper module, add an extra parameter to it, indicating if it should produce the stepper itself or the mounting holes.

```
stepper(holes=false);
difference(){board(); stepper(holes=true);}
```

Another trick you can do subtract holes from children() inside of the stepper module. and use it like:

```
stepper() { board(); }
```